# I'm in an iPhone provisioning mess -- Insight needed

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing, codesign

My app has been more or less ready to be submitted for a while now, but as usual, the overly complex provisioning nonsense that Apple forces developers to jump through is causing me an enormous amount of stress.  Initially the problem I was receiving was Invalid Codesign.  After trying every 'solution' i could find on the internet and failing, I decided that it would be best if I started fresh -- Deleted all my provioning profiles, cleaned up my itunes connect account, deleted all my keys and certificate from the keychain access and started from scratch.  The problem is that once I deleted by keys and developer certificate from the keychain access, I cant get them back!!!  I've tried restarting, I've tried installing it every way imaginable, but I just cant get anything to be listed in the 'keys' nor 'my certificates' sections of the keychain access.  I do have an iPhone edveloper profile in the 'certificates section' but this doesnt even seem to be of any use because when I look in the Organizer there are no developer profiles listed, and all my provisioning profiles warn "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain"

Someone please help me through this mess.  I've been developing my app for several months now and I already have an app in the App Store but Apple insists on making this process damn near impossible.  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Did you ever figure out the Invalid Codesign problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your public and private keys are automagically generated when required - if you use the certificate assistant to request a signing certificate as the provisioning profile describes you will find your new private/public keys created.

Once you begin this process you should also use spotlight to remove all .mobileprovision and .cer files you may have remaining in downloads, and also use organizer to remove profiles from devices. If you are starting from scratch you want to make sure none of that stuff remains to cause you problems.

This is an overcomplicated process to be sure, but once everything is really deleted and a fresh start is made it should be good for some time. The biggest problems I have had are when getting a new Mac and having hiccups with exporting/importing keys in an effort to keep my old certificates/provisioning valid.

Comment: My problem is that they keys aren't being created.  I get to the step where I download my development certificate and double click on the .cer, but there isn't any prompt like the one i see in the wizard image.  It just takes me to the Certificates category in the Organizer and the certificate is visible there, but there are no keys nor items in 'My Certificates'

Comment: Having had the fun I've had with the whole provisioning process, I would probably just take the opportunity to upgrade my hard drive, install a fresh OS and start again with a fresh OS install. At some point the time it takes to do that + the cost of a drive is less than the time you waste - sorry I can't suggest anything better.

Comment: cleaned up my hard drive and itunes connect profile to a blank slate.  I followed all instructions to the T and finally was able to get the public/private keys in the keychain access.  Only problem is, now I'm right back where I started a few days ago... I can build and run my app (everything works perfectly), except I get the warning "Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate (-19011)."  Thanks a lot for the advice, it got me out of the deep end, but I'm still in a crappy predicament.

Comment: So you've definitely gone and requested a distribution certificate, rather than using your development certificate?

Comment: Well, I hadn't tried submitting until earlier today and it worked fine with my distribution certificate.  nevertheless, i still cant compile using my dev certificate without getting the warning.